# Lumen AND OR conditions in Where clause

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am trying to run following query in Lumen Framework:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE (username = $username OR email = $username) AND password = $password AND flag = 1;
```

My Lumen code:

```
$login =  User::where('pass', '=', md5($pass))
               ->where('flag', '=', $flag)
               ->where('username', '=', $username)
               ->orWhere('email', '=', $username)->first();
```

Somehow this code always return true and bypass the login. What is wrong in that query?

When I remove `orWhere` from query it works perfect for username.

Comment: ... why are you using md5 for a password, in 2015? Laravel/Lumen automatically use `bcrypt()`, so you've overridden this manually.

Comment: Is your password hashed by md5()?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to group the two conditions (username and email) into a single condition (surrounded by parenthesis), you will have to do it like this:

```
User::where('pass', '=', md5($pass))
    ->where('flag', '=', $flag)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($username) {
        $query->where('username', '=', $username)
              ->orWhere('email', '=', $username);
    })->first();
```

[Here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres) is the documentation on advanced where conditions for the Laravel query builder (which Lumen uses).

Comment: I am getting an error: Undefined variable: username. I made sure, $username is there but still getting this error

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, yes, the $username variable is not within the closure's scope. I updated my answer.

Comment: Also the query is bypassing and returing true in all cases :(

Comment: @NewCo: the query here is `pass = "pass" and flag = "flag" or (conditions)`.

Comment: Oh, @Amelia is right, my bad. I edited my answer once again. Please try it now.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that what you want is this:

```
User::where('pass', '=', md5($pass))
    ->where('flag', '=', $flag)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($username) {
        $query->where('username', '=', $username)
              ->orWhere('email', '=', $username);
    })->first();
```

Also please don't use `md5`, try re hashing all of your passwords with bcrypt()

Answer (score 0):

Follow laravel advance where http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#advanced-wheres

```
User::where('pass', '=', md5($pass))
->where('flag', '=', $flag)
->where(function ($query) use ($username) {
    $query->where('username', '=', $username)
          ->where('email', '=', $username);
})->first();
```